# Pythonw batch file still shows console

Tags: python, batch-file, pythonw

I have created a `Python` script for which I don't want to see the console pop-up every time it's being ran. I tried the `pythonw.exe + .pyw` approach, and while the script works just fine, the console still pops-up regardless.

`.bat` file content:

`"C:\Users\mariu\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\mariu\test.pyw" pause`

And this is the inevitable console: [image]

Is there something am I missing?

Comment: A batch file runs its commands in a console window, if you don't want one, don't run your command from a batch file! Alternatively, you may find thst using `start` will mean that the inevitable console window will not show for very long, unless you're really wanting to use the `pause` command, which would be counterintuative.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm new to python and bat files in general and I'm obviously still missing basic stuff like this.

Comment: The Python installer should have set up your PATHEXT variable so that you don't even need to specify Pythonw.  Just type `C:\Users\mariu\test.pyw` all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and moved to powershell script, since my tasks needed to start in parallel, and batch script seems not to behave like that, even with pythonw.exe

A .ps1 with the lines below should do the work

```
& "C:\Users\mariu\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\mariu\test.pyw"
exit
```